# Как использовать transform: scale() без потери четкости при медленном transition?

Tags: css, css3, hover, transform, transition

Как использовать `transform: scale()` без потери четкости при медленном `transition`?
Допустим, `transform: scale(1.5)`, а `transition: all 1s linear`. При `:hover`, в момент увеличения, блок теряет свою четкость до момента окончания `transition: all 1s linear`. Это довольно-таки неудобно. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Может попробывать увеличить у картинки разрешение. Но это скорее всего хорошо сработает если у вас scale в целые числа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решается следующим образом:

```
img {
   image-rendering: optimizeQuality;
}
```

Comment: И так автоматом обычно ставится этот режим.

Comment: @Other автоматом ставится image-rendering: auto

Comment: Да, и это значение означает автоподбор, который обычно выбирает `optimizeQuality`.